# MYSQL: DISTINCT giving me duplicate

Tags: mysql

```
Select Distinct teacher.teacher_id as 'No',                             
-> teacher.empno as 'Emp. No.',                                                         
-> teacher.fname as 'First Name',                                                    
-> teacher.lname as 'Last Name',                                                        
-> college.name as 'College',                                                       
-> section.section_code as 'Section'                                                    
-> from teacher                                                                        
-> inner join college using (college_id)                                                
-> inner join section using (college_id)                                                
-> order by teacher.lname;
```

| No | Emp. No. | First Name | Last Name | College | Section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-05-201A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-05-101A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-02-201A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-02-101A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-01-201A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-01-101A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-08-201A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-08-101A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-06-201A |
| 10 | 100010 | Virgy | Cruz | CAS | PCAS-06-101A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-08-201A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-08-101A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-06-201A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-06-101A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-05-201A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-05-101A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-02-201A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-02-101A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-01-201A |
| 4 | 100004 | Jimmy | Fernandez | CAS | PCAS-01-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-20-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-20-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-19-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-19-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-18-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-18-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-17-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-17-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-05-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-05-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-01-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-01-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-25-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-25-101A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET | PCBET-22-201A |
| 2 | 100002 | Jasmine | Ferrer | CBET |  |

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your query is the join command you use. You should probably use `Left Join` to combine the tables. (And then select distinct might not be required at all)